# Can not create calendar view in custom list programatically using CSOM in Sharepoint online

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am not able to create calendar view in custom list programatically using CSOM in Sharepoint online. I get Server exception "Cannot complete this action. Please try again". I am able to do the same using UI but not through code. I used the following code

```
           `Web web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("myCal");
            context.Load(list);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            ViewCreationInformation vci = new ViewCreationInformation();
            vci.Title = "Calviews1";
            vci.ViewTypeKind = ViewType.Calendar;
            vci.RowLimit = 0;
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            View view = list.Views.Add(vci);
            context.ExecuteQuery();`
```

If i use the code to create any other type of view in custom List, it works. Also if I create Calendar View in a Calendar list it still works. But not just if I use the code to create Calendar view for Custom List

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer finally as told by Microsoft Support Team. 
We need to use `vci.ViewTypeKind = ViewType.Calendar | ViewType.Recurrence;`

Check the link for more details:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/463a0cc9-9036-493f-a770-d5ee3a103a92/can-not-create-calendar-view-in-custom-list-programatically-using-csom-in-sharepoint-online?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Answer (score -1):

you should use ExecuteQueryAsync in order to use the objects you load in the context, in the success callback of the function, instead of using ExecuteQuery.

more info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168907.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396